# Mysql error with UNION query

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count, union

```
select t1.tema,
    count(p.id_pregunta) as num_preguntas
from preguntas p
right join subtema s on p.id_subtema = s.id_subtema
join tema t on t.id_tema = s.id_tema
union
select t1.tema,
    count(r1.id_respuesta) as preg_respuesta
from respuestas r1
right join preguntas p1 on r1.id_pregunta = p1.id_pregunta
right join subtema s1 on p1.id_subtema = s1.id_subtema
right join tema t1 on t1.id_tema = s1.id_tema
group by t1.tema
order by preg_respuesta desc
```

What is wrong with this query? I'm getting this:

> error #1054 - Unknown column 'preg_respuesta' in 'order clause''

Please help me.

Comment: Could you write how the output should look like ?

Answer (score 3):

A `SELECT ... UNION` takes its column names from the first query. Try

```
... ORDER BY num_preguntas DESC
```

or

```
.... ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

(since you're sorting by the **2**nd column in the result.)

Answer (score 1):

I think problem in alias for *count* column. In first query you name it `num_preguntas` in second `preg_respuesta` in finel result this column have name by name from first query `num_preguntas`.

Change `orger by preg_respuesta desc` to `orger by num_preguntas desc`

Answer (score 0):

This is aliasing problem... put the table alias name in where the column `preg_respuesta` belongs.

Ex: **IF** `preg_respuesta` column is belong to table `respuestas` which have alias `r1`. the `order by` will look something like:

```
order by r1.preg_respuesta desc
```